# fixed point of a multivalued map

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, fixed-point-theorems, multivalued-functions, set-valued-analysis

Suppose I have a map $S:X \to Y$ between Banach spaces which is multivalued, so that $S(x)$ is a set.

I have shown that $S$ takes a closed ball of radius $R$ to itself, and it also is such that if $x_n \to x$ weakly, then there exists $y_n \in S(x_n)$ and $y \in S(x)$ such that $y_n \to y$ strongly.

Is this enough to conclude that $S$ has a fixed point? I.e. that there is a $z$ such that $z \in S(z)$? If $S$ were single valued, it is enough by Tikhonov's Fixed Point Theorem.

Is there something easy to apply in this case too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally no.  One usually also wants some regularity condition on the sets $S(x)$.  The standard requirement is for $S(x)$ to be convex for all $x$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakutani_fixed-point_theorem#Infinite-dimensional_generalizations), for example.$^1$  (Note: this is vacuously satisfied when considering functions, hence why such a condition is not stated for Tikhonov's fixed point theorem.)

As a simple counter example of what can go wrong without such a hypothesis, let $X = Y = \mathbb{R}$, and let
$$
S(x) = \begin{cases} -1 & \textrm{ if } x \ge 0 \\ 1 & \textrm{ if } x \le 0. \end{cases}
$$
$S$ clearly takes the unit ball about the origin to itself, is upper-hemicontinuous, and fixed point free.

---

$^1$ Convexity can be greatly relaxed.  The search terms to look up are 'acyclicity', 'Eilenberg-Montgomery fixed point theorem', and 'Vietoris-Begle theorem'.  Gorniewicz' *Topological Fixed Point Theory of Multivalued Mappings* is a comprehensive treatment of the subject that may interest you.